# Convert from MySQL to orientDB

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

We are currently re-engineering our system (Documents Management System) and we are moving from MySQL to use OrientDB, we are creating the migration tool, but we are faced with the problem of moving the data from RDMS mysql to orientDB, my question is: Is there any tool to easily migrate from MySQL to OrientDB and yes we are using orientDB as graphDB, my orient is v 2.2.10 (i have recently updated from 2.2.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [teleporter](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Teleporter-Home.html). It is compatible with MySQL.

OrientDB Teleporter is a tool that synchronizes a RDBMS to OrientDB database. You can use Teleporter to:

Import your existing RDBMS to OrientDB
Keep your OrientDB database synchronized with changes from the RDBMS. In this case the database on RDBMS remains the primary and the database on OrientDB a synchronized copy. Synchronization is one way, so all the changes in OrientDB database will not be propagated to the RDBMS
Teleporter is fully compatible with several RDBMS that have a JDBC driver: we successfully tested Teleporter with Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL and HyperSQL. Teleporter manages all the necessary type conversions between the different DBMSs and imports all your data as Graph in OrientDB.

NOTE: This feature is available only in the OrientDB Enterprise Edition. If you are interested in a commercial license look at OrientDB Subscription Packages.